# Image disappear when use NavigationPage inside TabbedPage Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I tried to make NavigationPage inside my tabbed page For first i used this code in my app.xaml.cs

```
    var tabbedPage = new Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage();
    tabbedPage.On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
    tabbedPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.White;
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new MainPage()  { Title = "myTabName", Icon = "Icon.png" });
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new MainPage() { Title = "myTabName", Icon = "Icon.png" });
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new MainPage() { Title = "myTabName", Icon = "Icon.png" });
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new MainPage() { Title = "myTabName", Icon = "Icon.png" });
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new MainPage() { Title = "myTabName", Icon = "Icon.png" });
    MainPage = tabbedPage;
```

Ok it works perfect.But when i tried with this -

```
tabbedPage.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new MainPage()  { Title = "myTabName", Icon = "Icon.png" }));
```

My Icon and title disappear.I dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `icon` and `title` on the `NavigationPage`:

```
tabbedPage.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new MainPage()) { Title = "myTabName", Icon = "Icon.png" });
```